# Mysql multiple joins group common field names into one

Tags: mysql

i am using below SQL query to join 3 tables on a main table

```
SELECT main.pricedrop, 
       t1.pid, 
       t2.pid, 
       t3.pid 
FROM   table_main AS main 
       LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 
              ON main.pid = t1.pid 
       LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
              ON main.pid = t2.pid 
       LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 
              ON main.pid = t3.pid 
ORDER  BY main.pricedrop ASC 
LIMIT  5;
```

above query gives me this result:

```
+-----------+---------+------+--------------+
| pricedrop | pid     | pid  | pid          |
+-----------+---------+------+--------------+
|      8.69 |    NULL | NULL | 665803977232 |
|      9.53 |    NULL | NULL |     82210815 |
|     11.11 | 1786429 | NULL |         NULL |
|     11.11 | 1786456 | NULL |         NULL |
|     13.91 |    NULL | NULL | 687074177857 |
+-----------+---------+------+--------------+
```

is there anyway i can get the result in this format:

```
+-----------+--------------+
| pricedrop | pid          |
+-----------+--------------+
|      8.69 | 665803977232 |
|      9.53 | 82210815     |
|     11.11 | 1786429      |
|     11.11 | 1786456      |
|     13.91 | 687074177857 |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: What if you use `RIGHT JOIN` for that needs?

Comment: The simplest way is using the `COALESCE` function: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function which would return first non null value like:

```
SELECT pricedrop, COALESCE(t1.pid, t2.pid, t3.pid) AS pid
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT main.pricedrop, ifnull(t1.pid, ifnull(t2.pid, t3.pid ))
FROM   table_main AS main 
       LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 
              ON main.pid = t1.pid 
       LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
              ON main.pid = t2.pid 
       LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 
              ON main.pid = t3.pid 
ORDER  BY main.pricedrop ASC 
LIMIT  5;
```